# Building a class inherit from QWidget but with _ZTVXYYY undefined

Tags: gcc, qt5

I am building the analogClock (class AnalogClock : public QWidget) example application under qtbase/example/widgets, but with following undefined symbol: _ZTV11AnalogClock...

And I objdump -t analogClock.exe to try find who reference this symbol, but nothing found...

MORE INFO:
As long as the class inherit from QWidget, and construct a object, then there will be a undefined symbol _ZTVXYYY, where X is the length of the class name, YYY is the class name.

so could you someone help point out what's this _ZTVXYYY symbol ?
And how to avoid this situation ?

Comment: From http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~dww4s/pubs/metaman_oo.pdf, it uses a
name mangling scheme that assigns _ZTV to virtual function tables. But I am still confusing why could result in such undefined error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the Makefile is  not generated by the correct qmake tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @thincal said, if Qt project is not properly configured, qmake will generate incorrect Makefile.

For example, if I'm writing a PLUGIN which inherits from QWidget, I have to:

- Add `Q_OBJECT` macro in the top of class definition;
- Add `CONFIG += plugin` in the project config file (with `.pro` suffix).